# strange interrmittent behavior regarding settings.py apparently

Tags: python, django

I am using a python package called "django simple captcha" and it enables you to change the font used to generate the captcha image by setting `CAPTCHA_FONT_PATH` in your settings file. However, I wanted to change `CAPTCHA_FONT_PATH` dynamically, every single time captcha was run, and to that end in my `views.py` was calling

```
import captcha.conf;
...
captcha.conf.settings.CAPTCHA_FONT_PATH = BASE_DIR + '/fonts/' + random.choice(cfonts)
```

However, it is only sporadically updating the `CAPTCHA_FONT_PATH` that captcha is actually using for some unknown reason. Sometimes it updates, sometimes it doesn't (completely unrelated to the random.choice call, btw). For the above I've also tried using `setattr`, but no change in behavior.

`CAPTCHA_FONT_PATH` is only being accessed by captcha in its `views.py` file in a function called `captcha_image`:

```
from captcha.conf import settings
...

font = ImageFont.load(settings.CAPTCHA_FONT_PATH)
```

and also in its own `settings.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
...

CAPTCHA_FONT_PATH = getattr(settings, 'CAPTCHA_FONT_PATH'...)
```

So is there something I don't understand about settings.py in general.

```
Django 1.8 (mod_wsgi 4.2.8/Python 2.7)
```

Edit:  I'm not absolutely sure its related to settings, as sometimes I can't tell for certain `captcha_image` is even being called every iteration, but don't know why it wouldn't be.  Maybe someone has familiarity with this package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this line is at the top of your module

```
captcha.conf.settings.CAPTCHA_FONT_PATH = BASE_DIR + '/fonts/' + random.choice(cfonts)
```

then it will be loaded once when the views.py is loaded, not every time the view runs. You need to move that line into a view to have it regenerated each time the view runs.

Note that Django discourages [altering settings at runtime](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime). Your case is slightly different, because you are altering `captcha.conf.settings`, but it still looks a bit strange. Ideally, I guess you would change *django simple captcha* so that it allowed you to define a callable for the font path instead of requiring a constant.

Comment: No, its being called in a view function, right before the captcha form is returned.

Comment: Thanks for the find about not altering settings.  Weird.

Comment: I might come back and mark this as the answer, though I wrote a variant that didn't use settings, and was still getting this weird sporadic behavior. But Django does say (without explanation) don't alter settings at runtime.

Comment: I will mark this as the answer, as you also suggested passing a callable to captcha, which is what I did and it worked.  Specifically I had captcha check if CAPTCHA_FONT_PATH was a function, and if so, call it to get the path.  Then I put that random.choice etc in this function.  The beauty is I can still pass in a static path if I want as well.  But anyway, thanks dude.